# PHP - Mysqli maneira correta

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou a começar a utilizar mysqli nos meus projetos, no entanto vi duas maneiras de fazer uma conecção:

Uma delas é a simples e igual ao `mysql_connect` `$db = mysqli_connect(...);` que vi no w3schools.

Outra é a `$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');`

Há diferença entre os 2? Qual é o melhor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não tem melhor, no fim dá tudo na mesma.

Olhando o manual do PHP:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php

Você vê que a função `mysqli_connect` é um sinônimo do método `__construct()` (que é o que acontece quando você usa o `new`), portanto,

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');
```

é a mesmíssima coisa que

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');
```

Use o que "combinar" mais com seu estilo de código. Como é PHP, que não passa de um "processador de script" que nem mantém o estado interno entre chamadas, diferente de linguagens compiladas onde os módulos ou mesmo a aplicação toda roda no mesmo contexto, dá pra misturar os paradigmas sem problema nenhum, sem vantagens e desvantagens significativas, e por isso acaba sendo questão de "estética" e realmente de você escolhe o que combina com seu fluxo de trabalho.